# Deploy Laravel Vue app with ratchet websockets

Tags: laravel, vue.js, deployment, websocket, ratchet

I have an application that works with web sockets. In development, I created a console command that starts the socket server.  I deployed the application, using the cpanel, how can I run my console command once?  I think that the cron job is not suitable for this.  The front is written in Vue, I tried to send an asynchronous request, which from the controller launches the command for the socket server if the web sockets are not connected (I check this at the front), but this not working correctly. I tried open in browser php file which launches the websocket server, but this not working correctly too.

Comment: Can you SSH into the server?

Comment: yes, but I need the web socket server to always be started, and not through console launch

Comment: Look into `supervisord` its a Linux tool, which will automatically starts and keeps open a given process.

Comment: thx for you feedback, but I did otherwise. I ran the nohup php /path_for_my_script in the console and ran this process in the background. This works for me

Comment: Just keep in mind, if your process exits due to error or reboot, you will need to manually restart it.